# Wordpress don't show full image if postformat is video

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I have a very simple blog page with different post-types, I'm using a plugin that looks for videos and automatically creates images from the video which is great on the blog listing page. What I don't want is the full image to be displayed when viewing the post, I just want it to show the video and no image as the video and image look the same. You can see what I mean [here](http://webcontrolcentre.co.uk/wordpress_sass/lush-life-zara-larsson/)

Is there a way of not displaying the full image on posts with the video post format?

Comment: Just dont use that plugin. Take the embed code of the video from youtube and give it the sizes of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin you're using is setting the image that it took from the video as a *featured image*. Coincidentally, the theme you're using is displaying this featured image in posts in the theme.

To get rid of the image in your posts you will want to make the theme stop displaying the featured image. You can de a few things here: edit the template file the theme is using and remove the line of code that displays the featured image, use a different theme altogether, or (if your theme offers this functionality) turn off the featured image in theme options.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I do want featured images just not on posts that have a video, I have created a seperate template called content-video.php but don't know how to remove featured images just for that template?